# JAXB, MOXy; Can I use @XmlPaths and @XmlElements to model a choice if I have an @XmlPath(".") self mapping?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

Suppose I have a schema with a type which has an inner choice;

```
<complexType name="RootType">
        <sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <choice>
                <sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <element name="A" type="tns:A"></element>
                    <element name="B" type="tns:B"></element>
                    <element name="C" type="tns:C"></element>
                </sequence>
                <element name="P" type="tns:P" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
                <element name="Q" type="tns:Q" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            </choice>
        </sequence>
</complexType>
```

I might want to represent the sequence of A, B, C by a wrapping java class to distinguish it from the P or Q. I represent structure which as no name using MOXy's ['self mappings'](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts005.htm#CHDGBEAC);

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "RootType", propOrder = {
    "seq1",
    "p",
    "q"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="TopLevel")
public class RootType {


    @XmlPath(".")
    private InnerSequence seq1;
    @XmlElement(name = "P")
    private P p;
    @XmlElement(name = "Q")
    private Q q;

    public static class InnerSequence 
    {
        @XmlElement(name = "A")
        public A a;
        @XmlElement(name = "B")
        public B b;
        @XmlElement(name = "C")
        public C c;
     }
}
```

See this previous [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105486/jaxb-represent-nested-model-group-schema-components-with-a-java-object-hierarch/33693903#33693903)

But suppose I prefered to represent that in a way more natural to a schema choice;

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "RootType2", propOrder = {
    "choice1"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="TopLevel2")
public class RootType2 {


    @XmlPaths({
        @XmlPath("."),
        @XmlPath("P"),
        @XmlPath("Q"),
        })
    @XmlElements({
         @XmlElement(type=InnerSequence.class),
         @XmlElement(name = "P", type=P.class),
         @XmlElement(name = "Q", type=Q.class),
    })
    public Object choice1;

    public static class InnerSequence 
    {
        @XmlElement(name = "A")
        public A a;
        @XmlElement(name = "B")
        public B b;
        @XmlElement(name = "C")
        public C c;
    }
}
```

Moxy will marshall

```
    RootType2 root1 = new RootType2();
    InnerSequence inner1 = new InnerSequence();
    root1.choice1 = inner1;
    inner1.a = new A();
    inner1.b = new B();
    inner1.c = new C();
    inner1.a.setOne("Hello One A");
    inner1.b.setOne("Hello One B");
    inner1.c.setOne("Hello One C");
```

as expected to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TopLevel2 xmlns="http://www.example.org/Schema1">
   <A>
      <one>Hello One A</one>
   </A>
   <B>
      <one>Hello One B</one>
   </B>
   <C>
      <one>Hello One C</one>
   </C>
</TopLevel2>
```

But when I unmarshall  it RootType2 is empty; on remarshalling I get;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TopLevel2 xmlns="http://www.example.org/Schema1"/>
```

Okay, so perhaps I need to kick MOXy into life by telling it somehow that InnerSequence  should be mapped if A or B or C are in TopLevel, so I  try this XPath (having checked that it works in standalone java);

```
public class RootType2 {


    @XmlPaths({
        @XmlPath("self::node()[A|B|C]/."),
        @XmlPath("P"),
        @XmlPath("Q"),
        })
    @XmlElements({
         @XmlElement(type=InnerSequence.class),
         @XmlElement(name = "P", type=P.class),
         @XmlElement(name = "Q", type=Q.class),
    })
    public Object choice1;

...
```

I then cannot Marshall, getting an NPE:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NullPointerException]]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:508)
    at uk.co.his.test.complexSequenceAndChoice.TestSchema3.testNACT1_jaxb(TestSchema3.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:501)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.OutputStreamRecord.outputStreamWrite(OutputStreamRecord.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.OutputStreamRecord.outputStreamWrite(OutputStreamRecord.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.FormattedOutputStreamRecord.openStartElement(FormattedOutputStreamRecord.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.MarshalRecord.openStartGroupingElements(MarshalRecord.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLChoiceObjectMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLChoiceObjectMappingNodeValue.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLChoiceObjectMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLChoiceObjectMappingNodeValue.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshalStreamOrWriter(XMLMarshaller.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.
```

Is there any way to use a Self Mapping in conjunction with an @XmlPaths and  @XmlElements?

Same question on [Eclipselink MOXy forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1072133/)

Comment: Hi,I know it's quite old but even I'm stuck in this issue lately.  Do you know some resolution or workaround to resolve the issue? Following are my observations: I tried to debug the `Moxy` code but still no luck in finding the solution. But I got to know that the issue is happening due to the `annotation @XmlPath(".")`. As we have given the `(".")` all the fields will be `unmarshalled` into the `Map<String, Object>`. I guess this is the intended workflow for `Moxy` so not a bug. I tried a lot of workarounds but no luck. My post here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67648941/7584240